# Formatting md5sum differently?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find the md5sum of files recursively and list these files alphabetically. However, in my final output I don't want the sum to actually show up. For example if I issue:

```
find -not -empty -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \;
```

I get this:

```
0df8724ef24b15e54cc9a26e7679bb90  ./doc1.txt
d453430ce039863e242365eecaad7888  ./doc2.txt
53b2e8ae1dfaeb64ce894f75dd6b957c  ./test.sh~
1ba03849883277c3c315d5132d10d6f0  ./md5file.txt
6971b4dbbd6b5b8d1eefbadc0ecd1382  ./test.sh
```

is there a simple way make this command to show only the files like:

```
./doc1.txt
./doc2.txt
./test.sh~
./md5file.txt
./test.sh
```

thx!

Comment: Remove `-exec md5sum "{}" \;`.

Comment: Yes if it is not required of md5sum output remove `-exec md5sum "{}" \;` and give simple `-print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cyrus and Sriharsha say, simply using:

```
find -not -empty -type f
```

will give you the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the output of find command to awk or cut.

```
find -not -empty -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; | awk '{print $2}'
```

**OR**

Use sed if the filename contains spaces.

```
find -not -empty -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; | sed 's/^[^ ]\+ \+//'
```